# Travelport uAPI php SoapClient

Tags: php, xml, soap, travelport-api

I need to develop a PHP web based application using Travelport uAPI. I'm able to connect to the webservice using the function `curl_init()` writing all xml request, but I'm stuck trying to do it with `SoapClient` class.
I'm using this example and doesn't work:

http://demo.travelportuniversalapi.com/Home/SampleCode

I don't know what I'm doing wrong. Anyone knows a working sample code/project in PHP using SoapClient class? I've searched in the web, but I couldn't find anything in PHP.

Comment: First, ensure that the xml requests you're sending are valid. They have a pretty good test utility to do that: http://developer.travelport.com/euf/assets/developer-network/downloads/Travelport_API_Test_Tool.zip

So make sure that your requests are working with that test utility, and then try to bring it to your php code. Also, don't forget that XML is case-sensitive (I almost killed myself because of that :))

Comment: Hi @castledom04, can you provide the full code for above SOLVED sample., or can you explain the parameters passed to _doRequest() method.

Answer (score 2):

(Answered in a question edit. Converted to a community wiki answer. See [What is the appropriate action when the answer to a question is added to the question itself?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/267434/what-is-the-appropriate-action-when-the-answer-to-a-question-is-added-to-the-que) )

The OP wrote:

> At last the way to reach my solution has been using the Travelport test tool writing my xml requests and passing a string containing the xml.
>
> Needed for authentication:
>
> ```
> $this->credentials["login"]=$user;
> $this->credentials["password"]=$pass;
> $this->credentials["traceid"]=$traceid; (branchcode)
> ```
>
> Then I create the soap client:
>
> ```
> $client = new SoapClient("galileo/air_v20_0/Air.wsdl", $this->credentials);
> $rsp=$client->__doRequest($this->request, $this->credentials['location'], $this->credentials['soapaction'], $this->credentials['soap_version']);
> ```
>
> And this covers my needs :)
>
> Now I'm trying to pass the request info using SoapClient and WSDL functions in this post [WSDL functions with the same name. How to choose one?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14748125/wsdl-functions-with-the-same-name-how-to-choose-one/14991027?noredirect=1#14991027)